# How to display an error message in gui?

Tags: arrays, user-interface, matlab

Hye guyz. I need an assistance with this. I have a figure of table. The user will insert a data into the table. If the user suddenly wrong insert the data, the table will be 'NaN'. My question is how i want to make the table does not display 'NaN' on the table but I want an error message appear. I have this coding:

```
function Mytable1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if isnan(Mytable1)

set(hObject, 'Data', 0);

errordlg('Input must be a number','Error');

end

handles.Mytable2 = hObject;

guidata(hObject,handles);
```

But there is an error with this code. Is this coding are correct to answer my question?

#### Update:

I did this coding on Mytable1_CellEditCallback. It still have error. Is this code true??

```
Mytable1=get(hObject,'Data')

if isnan(Mytable1)

set(hObject, 'Data', 0);
h=errordlg('Oh noes!','Error');
set(h, 'WindowStyle', 'modal');
uiwait(h);
return
end

handles.Mytable2 = hObject;
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

This is the error:

Mytable1 =

```
[1]    []    []
 []    []    []
 []    []    []
 []    []    []
```

??? Undefined function or method 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> fyp_editor>Mytable1_CellEditCallback at 795
if ~isnan(Mytable1)

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> fyp_editor at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)fyp_editor('Mytable1_CellEditCallback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

??? Error while evaluating uitable CellEditCallback

Comment: The error message will help, as well as the line defining this callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in this code. Let me count the ways.

1. `function Mytable1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)`

   The create function is executed at object creation, i.e. when the GUI is built. It is never executed otherwise, and thus it's a function you'll rarely ever want to modify. What you do want to modify is `Mytable1_Callback`
2. `if isnan(Mytable1)`

   `Mytable1` has not been defined within the function. Thus, this line will give you an error. Maybe you meant to add a line `Mytable1=get(hObject,'Data')`? Also, since `Mytable1` is a cell array, you have to check the elements for NaNs using `cellfun`, i.e. write `if any(cellfun(@isnan,Mytable1(:)))`.
3. `set(hObject, 'Data', 0);`

   This line is most likely fine.
4. `errordlg('Input must be a number','Error');`

   While this line is not an error, it won't behave as intended - The message pops up, but the function continues executing. Either you should write `error('input must be a number)`, or write `h=errordlg('Oh noes!');uiwait(h);return`
5. `end`

   Look, another line that is fine!
6. `handles.Mytable2 = hObject; guidata(hObject,handles);`

   With this, you overwrite the handle to `Mytable2` with the handle to `Mytable1`. Is that REALLY what you want?

Comment: Ok.. Let me tell you true process. I have a figure of table and a pushbuttons. The user will insert the data into the table but assume the user accidentally insert a wrong data. For example:


If the user only want to use C1 and C2 but the user accidentally insert a data on C3(row) then he delete the data from C3 at column ALPHA and the column ALPHA at row C3 will become NAN. So how i want an error message says 'Please complete C3' and I dont want it become 'NAN' but i want to leave it blank. How can i make it?

Answer (score 1):

```
if isnan(Mytable1)
```

Mytable is a cell array. Try this:

```
if any(isnan(cell2mat(Mytable1)))
```

---

However, there migth be an easier way, the Cell edit callback gets two inputs: the calling Object and the eventdata (and  handles in guide). In the eventdata has following Fields:

- Indices: 1-by-2 array containing the row and column indices of the cell the user edited.
- PreviousData: Previous cell data. The default is an empty matrix, [].
- EditData: User-entered string.
- NewData: Value that MATLAB wrote to the Data property array. It is either the same as EditData or a converted value.
  The NewData property is empty if MATLAB detects an error in the user-entered data.
- Error: Error message returned if MATLAB detects an error in the user-entered data.
  The Error property is empty when MATLAB successfully writes the value to the Data property.
  If the Error property is not empty, then the CellEditCallback can display the string, or it can attempt to fix the problem.

Source:http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable-properties.html#zmw57dd0e748724

With NewData or Error this should be  possible to handle error checking.

for example:

```
MyTable_CellEditCallback(hObj,event,handles)

if isempty(event.NewData)
    h=errordlg('Oh noes!','Error');
    set(h, 'WindowStyle', 'modal');
    uiwait(h);
    return
end

% The rest of the function
end
```